# How to access a class variable with this + 'another variable'

Tags: javascript

I want to access a public variable in my class with 'this' + 'a variable' from inside a function but I can't get it to work.

I have already tried to access it via the bracket method:

this[myVar];

but it doesn't works.

```
export class abc {
    public a = true;
    public b = true;

    public someFunction(parameter) {
      this.'parameter' = false; // <-- Here I want to set either a or b to false depending on the value of the parameter
    }
}
```

Comment: `this[parameter] = false;` And call using `someFunction('a');`. Please share a [mcve] of your attempt to do `this[myVar];`.

Comment: may I ask why the Angular tag?

Comment: If this is angular, the assumption is that you're using `TypeScript`. In which case, I'd recommend a little more "Syntactical Sugar" here...

Answer (score 1):

Things to mention here:

1. If you're simply just trying to set `this[parameter]`, a function is a
   little much here. Have you thought about a ternary condition?
2. In your current code, your function would only set `a` (By the way,
   this should be `this.a` as `a` does not exist in that function scope.)

Here is what I would suggest. Do a quick check on the `this` to make sure the `parameter` exists, if it does, set the value to `false`.

```
export class abc {
    public a = true;
    public b = true;

    public someFunction(parameter) {
        if (parameter && this.hasOwnProperty(parameter)) {
            this[parameter] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not what his code comment says: "<-- Here I want to set either a or b to false depending on the value of the parameter". Key part "dependeing on the value of the paramater" I assume he means set it to the opposite of whatever the value is (aka: toggle) I could be misreading that though. OP isn't chiming in so hard to tell

Comment: I understood that OP wants to do: `someFunction('a')` - which in response will set the (by default `true`) to `false`. As if saying: *"If an existent class param name was provided as argument - set it to false."* BTW classes are the worst JS feature ever invented. Douglas admitted that too. - But classes (in this Node  era - attracting more and more BE devs) convinced BE developers that JS is finally worth their attention :D :D

Comment: Also worth noticing that `public` is still in TC39 st.3 proposal (Babel needed for the rescue)

Comment: Technically speaking, he did tag it as angular so the assumption is he's using TypeScript